# Не устанавливается значения свойства PdfFreeTextAnnotation.Opacity

Tags: c#, setter

Всем привет. Есть приложение WPF. Там используются SyncFusion контролы. Я пытаюсь создать аннотоцаю

```
PdfFreeTextAnnotation freeText = new PdfFreeTextAnnotation(new 
RectangleF(50, 100, 100, 50));
//Sets properties to the annotation
freeText.MarkupText = "Free Text with Callout";
freeText.TextMarkupColor = new PdfColor(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
freeText.Font = new PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.Helvetica, 7f);
//freeText.Bounds = new RectangleF(50, 100, 100, 50);
freeText.Opacity = 0.5f;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(freeText.Opacity);
freeText.Color = new PdfColor(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
freeText.BorderColor = new PdfColor(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
freeText.Border = new PdfAnnotationBorder(.5f);
freeText.LineEndingStyle = PdfLineEndingStyle.OpenArrow;
freeText.AnnotationFlags = PdfAnnotationFlags.Default;
freeText.Text = "Free Text";
PointF[] points = { new PointF(100, 400), new PointF(100, 450) };
freeText.CalloutLines = points;

AnnotationAdd = freeText;
```

Дальше оно попадает сюда

```
    private static void PdfAnnotationAddedChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var view = (WpfPdfViewer)d;
        var viewer = ((WpfPdfViewer)d).Viewer;

        try
        {
            var lDoc = viewer.LoadedDocument;

            int currentPage = viewer.CurrentPage;

            PdfAnnotation annotation = (PdfAnnotation)e.NewValue;

            lDoc.Pages[currentPage - 1].Annotations.Add(annotation);

            view.PerformAutoSave();

            //view.Load(lDoc);

        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
        }
    }
```

`WpfPdfViewer` наследуется от `PdfViewerControl`

Вот всё свойства устанавливаются нормально, кроме свойства `Opacity`. Оно вечно равно 0.

Сетер выглядит так

```
set
  {
    if ((double) value < 0.0 || (double) value > 1.0)
      throw new ArgumentException("Valid value should be between 0 to 1.");
    if ((double) this.m_opacity == (double) value)
      return;
    this.m_opacity = value;
  }
```

Скорее всего проблема в Геттере

```
get
  {
    this.m_opacity = 
        !this.m_dictionary.Items.ContainsKey(new PdfName("CA")) ? 0.0f : this.m_dictionary.Items[new PdfName("CA")] as PdfNumber).FloatValue;
    return this.m_opacity;
  }
```

Но что это за `m_dictionary` и `new PdfName("CA")`

Есть идеи?

Comment: `Debug.WriteLine(freeText.Opacity);` сразу после установки пишет 0? Или значение меняется где-то в конце?

Comment: @default locale всё время.

Comment: Точно нигде значение далее не изменяется? Если посмотреть это поле, то изначально при инициализации оно имеет значение: `private float m_opacity = 0.9f;` А setter у свойства Opacity выглядит так: `set { if ((double) value < 0.0 || (double) value > 1.0) throw new ArgumentException("Valid value should be between 0 to 1."); this.m_opacity = value; }`

Comment: @Kazantsev да, я немного изменил вопрос. При чем 0 как после инициализации так и потом. И так тоже 0 `PdfFreeTextAnnotation freeText = new PdfFreeTextAnnotation(new 
RectangleF(50, 100, 100, 50)) { Opacity = 1 };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В конечном итоге выяснилось, что когда сохраняешь файл с этой аннотацией - свойство `Opacity` имеет нужное значение. Но когда пытаюсь получить его Getter выдает 0...
Также контрол, который мы используем для отображения pdf. Не поддерживает текстовые аннотации, поэтому я думал что их `Opacity` установлен в `0`. Если открыть файл в Adobe Acrobat - всё работает.